# Can I sell apps on the apple's US app store market?

Tags: iphone

given [Apple's bizarre geographical segregation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3897/how-to-change-the-language-of-the-app-store-and-itunes) I was wondering if, as an Italian, I am allowed to create an English application sold on the US app store for $0.99 (regardless of the current USD <=> EUR exchange rates).

It seems a really stupid question and I really hope that I can but who knows, since I can't buy them maybe I can't sell them either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  An enrolled iOS developer can choose the countries in which they want their approved apps to appear in Apple's iTunes App store: such as one, all, or even none.

For sales from the U.S. App store, it greatly helps to have the app and app store description Internationalized to English.